# how to print name of month with first letter capital using format_cldr("LLL")

Tags: perl

I am using format_cldr("LLL") which gives me jan, feb, mar, ... But I need first letter capital: Jan, Feb, Mar, ...

I tried using ucfirst(), but no success.

here is my piece of code:

```
while ($i < 13) {
  my $d = DateTime->new(year=>1111, month => $i, day=>1);
  $d->set_locale($self->context->locale);
  @$climate[$i-1]->{month_name} = $d->format_cldr("LLL");
  $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Need help, thanks in advance

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::CLDR#cldr_format

Comment: tried not working

Comment: What locale are you working with? On my system if I put in `de-DE` or `en-US` or `en-UK` it comes out as _Jan_, _Feb_ and so on. Anyway putting a `ucfirst` around the `$f->format_cldr` call should suffice.

Comment: I am using for Norwegian

Comment: you mean: ucfirst($d->format_cldr("LLL")) ?

Comment: yes, it is working, thanks a lot. Issue is solved.

Comment: Yeah. You take the return value and `ucfirst` it. That'll return a new value.

Comment: Next time, please try to clean your code up to be a self-contained example. Something along the lines of `use DateTime; my $d = DateTime->now; $d->set_locale('nb-NO'); say $d->format_cldr("LLL");` would have been much easier to read for us, thus making it easier to help. Also see [mcve] if you are not sure what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you tried `ucfirst` but you didn't show us how.

This will work:

```
 @$climate[$i-1]->{month_name} = ucfirst $d->format_cldr("LLL");
```